# How to close the browser in Tricentis Testim?

Tags: testim.io

I'm a fresher in Testim.io, I need to close the browser at the end of my tests. In the official documentation I haven't found it. Anyone knows how to do it? thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to close the browser window. Testim does it instead.
Anyway you could add the custoom JS action with window.close() but it could fail your test. So it is unnecessary action in Testim.